# django doesnt add users upon submit

Tags: python, django

Im really stumped on why my models.py wont submit users email and pass to the database when I hit login . It doesnt show up in the Django admin page. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you  !! I pasted the models and view.py.

This is what I have so far:

views.py

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render

from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
#from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

#from . import views
# Create your views here.

def login(request):
    return render(request, 'login.html')

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("TESTINGGINGIGNGING")
            form.save()
           password=raw_password)
            #login(request, user)
            #return HttpResponse("success")
            return redirect('login.html')
        else:
            #this means the form is not valid
            #so you need to provide the varibles as they were submitted, so the user can change it to proper values
            form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'signup_form.html', {'form': form})
```

signupform.html (form)

```
{% extends 'signup.html' %}

{% block body %}

    <form method = "post" action = ".">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p}}
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

models.py

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user')
    photo = FileField(verbose_name=_("Profile Picture"),
                      upload_to=upload_to("main.UserProfile.photo", "profiles"),
                      format="Image", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(default='', blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default='')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=True)
    organization = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

signup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Login</title>
  {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'signup.css' %}">
  }
  </head>


<body>
</div>
<div class='login'>
  <div class='login_title'>
    <span>Sign Up</span>
  </div>
  <div class='login_fields'>
    <div class='login_fields__user'>
      <div class='icon'>
        <img src='http://d2nysvt2e2u12u.cloudfront.net/img/NPLwebsite17_header_mobile_accountBtn.png?v=34534534'>
      </div>

      <input placeholder='Username' type='text' name = 'Username'>
        <div class='validation'>
          <img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/217233/tick.png'>
        </div>
      </input>
    </div>

    <div class='login_fields__password'>
      <div class='icon'>
        <img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9e/Lock_icon.png'>
      </div>
      <input placeholder='Password' type='password' name = 'Password'>
      <div class='validation'>
          </div>

    </div>
    <div class='login_fields__submit'>
      <input type='submit' formmethod="post" value='Submit'>



<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>

    <script  src="{% static 'signup.js' %}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Include the view which that template submits to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `models.py` file where you have the `UserProfile` class defined, add two signal receivers to create & save the profile;

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

That should create a profile object when a new user is created, then update the profile each time the user is saved.

Sorry, I misunderstood the question.

If you want to see the profile fields on the user admin you need to create your own admin class for `User`.

You need to add inlines for your profile;

```
class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'Profile'
    fk_name = 'user'

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (UserProfileInline, )

    def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return list()
        return super(CustomUserAdmin, self).get_inline_instances(request, obj)
```

Comment: i added all that in, it doesnt work. What is stopping it from being read? Thank you so much!

Comment: If you're saving the `User` model, nothing is stopping them because they get executed every time you save the `User`. Check your terminal. If you're not seeing profiles created, something else is at fault.

Comment: @coderManzala666 Sorry, misunderstood your question. You need to use inline admin classes to get the profiles to show on the users in django admin.

Answer (score 1):

If your model is not showing up in Admin, make sure you have registered it in the admin.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myproject.myapp.models import UserProfiles

admin.site.register(UserProfiles)
```

To make this snippet work you need to replace myproject and myapp with your own names.

Comment: It still doesnt add to the database. I updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

the error was actually in my signup_form that i extended from signup.html.The html submit button was not working. so I had to add it to my signup_form manually.